# Radio Buttons not working when in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

first of all i'm not sure if i'm in the right topic for this if i'm not, please tell me but anyway, i have this code

```html
<audio id="radioplayer" src="http://habbohol.radioca.st/;" autoplay="autoplay" ></audio>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('radioplayer').play()"><div id="play"></div></a>
<a href="#"onclick="document.getElementById('radioplayer').pause()"><div id="stop"></div></a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('radioplayer').volume += 0.1"><div id="volup"></div></a>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('radioplayer').volume -= 0.1"><div id="voldown"></div></a>
```

It's for my site and i'm trying to get them to work, but when its in a div the buttons never play/stop/go up/down but if it's in a image or word for example it plays just fine, the odd thing it was working earlier in a div with the exact same code but with different div codes.  It would be really appreciated if you could help, I believe this is Javascript but i'm not paralytically sure tbh

Comment: Edit your post and put that code into it. (Formatted properly)

Answer (score 0):

I listened the music but your divs are empty if you want to see your link you need put a string into you div like: `<div>Button</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to put the semicolon after what's in the onclick quotations. 
Try this (assuming the functions in themselves work):

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('radioplayer').play();"><div id="play"></div></a>
```